# Checkbox with ngfor

Tags: html, angular, events, checkbox, ngfor

I have a component that is being for-looped. When I click one (`app-product-card`), I want its corresponding checkbox to be true or checked. How do I do that? I have this html

```
<div class="list-content fluid">
    <div class="products-cards" *ngFor="let product of dataSource['docs']">
        <div class="ui checkbox">
            <input class="singleCheckbox" type="checkbox" [checked]="product">
            <label hidden></label>
        </div>
        <app-product-card [product]="product" (click)="select(product)"></app-product-card>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Difficult to help until you share the value of dataSource['docs']. Need to see its structure. Your product should have a attribute that is boolean in type. You got to bind the [checked] attribute of checkbox inside ngfor with this attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You use local reference of child component like I did below:

```
<div class="list-content fluid">
    <div class="products-cards" *ngFor="let product of dataSource['docs']">
        <div class="ui checkbox">
            <input class="singleCheckbox" type="checkbox" [checked]="appProduct.product===product"> // Here you need match your currently selected product
            <label hidden></label>
        </div>
        <app-product-card #appProduct [product]="product" (click)="select(product)"></app-product-card>
    </div>
</div>

App Product Comp: TS

public product;

select(product){ this.product = product;}
```